# Haskell: Memory hog with DP despite using (2D) array

Tags: haskell, memory, multidimensional-array, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve a dynamic programming problem from a contest which puts limits on execution time and memory, naturally. Roughly, the stripped off version of the problem is to first produce a table row-wise, and then process every column, which involves "pairing" elements with their vertically opposite counterpart. This leads me to think that maintaining the whole table in memory is necessary. After using arrays, as suggested [here](https://jelv.is/blog/Lazy-Dynamic-Programming/), speed is okay but the program is still hogging memory.

### Problem

Given two integers `k` and `n`, define

```
dp[j][0] = dp[j][n+1] = 0               for j=0,...k,
dp[0][m] = 1                            for m=1,...,n,
dp[j][m] = dp[j-1][m-1] + dp[j-1][m+1]  for j=0,...,k and m=1,...,n.
```

Let `vs[m] = sum [dp[j][m] * dp[k-j][m] | j<-[0..k]]` for all `m=1,...,n`.

I need to compute `vs[1],...,vs[n]` and below is my code. (The `solve` function, that is. Since the result can be large numbers we compute them modulo `10^9+7`.)

```
{-# LANGUAGE Safe #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -O2 #-}

import safe Control.Arrow ((>>>))
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as TI
import qualified Data.Map as M
import qualified Data.Array as A
import Data.List
import Data.Function

main :: IO ()
main = TI.getContents >>= (T.lines >>> drop 0 >>> tcio >>> (mapM_ putStrLn)) where
    tcio :: [T.Text] -> [String]
    tcio [] = []
    tcio (nkq : rest) = ((:[]). istoline . solve . linetois) nkq  ++ tcio rest;
    linetoi t = f 0 t where f n t = if (T.null) t then n else f (10*n + (on (-) fromEnum (T.head t) '0') ) (T.tail t) ;
    linetois = (map linetoi).(T.words); linestoiss = map linetois;
    itoline = show; istoline = unwords . (map itoline); isstolines = map istoline

solve :: [Int] -> [Int]
solve [n,k,_] = vs where
    dpf 0 m = if m==0 || m==n+1 then 0 else 1
    dpf j m = if m==0 || m==n+1 then 0 else (dp A.! (j-1) A.! (m-1)) `madd` (dp A.! (j-1) A.! (m+1))
    dp = A.listArray (0,k)  [(A.listArray (0,n+1) [dpf j m | m <- [0..(n+1)]]) | j<-[0..k]]
    vs = [foldl1' madd ([(dp A.! j A.! m) `mmult` (dp A.! (k-j) A.! m) | j<-[0..k]]) | m<-[0..(n+1)]]
    madd = modp (+)
    mmult a b = fromInteger $ modp (*) (toInteger a) (toInteger b)
    modp f a b = (f a b)`mod` (10^9+7)
```

### Issue

For `k=5000` and `n=1000`, it is consuming more than 2GB of memory! That is way above 1 GB, considering that the actual question from the contest, where the limit set is 1GB, asks more.

Profiling result is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WJFY_XdqDT6sbpLYB-31ko8uBrx_Wx82/view?usp=sharing).  I am wondering if I am using the Array structure efficiently. Does the list comprehension fed to the `A.listArray` imply the creation of a 2D list internally, somewhat defeating the purpose? How else can we optimize memory if at all?

Comment: And by the way, converting to `Integer` and back is not necessary. `Int` is 64 bits on modern machines, which is more than enough to store `(10^9+7)^2`; if you are paranoid, import `Data.Int` and use `Int64` to work even on legacy machines.

Comment: I did not find `Int64` to be better than `Integer` in arithmetic nor in IO/parsing.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother with arrays. Go like this:

```hs
import Control.Monad

modulus :: Int
modulus = 10^9 + 7

plus :: Int -> Int -> Int
plus x y = (x + y) `rem` modulus

times :: Int -> Int -> Int
times x y = (x * y) `rem` modulus

initialize :: Int -> [Int]
initialize n = [0] ++ replicate (n-2) 1 ++ [1]

step :: [Int] -> [Int]
step xs = [0] ++ zipWith plus xs (drop 2 xs) ++ [0]

v :: [Int] -> Int
v xs = sum (zipWith times xs (reverse xs))

main :: IO ()
main = forever $ do
    line <- getLine
    n:k:_ <- mapM readIO (words line)
    putStrLn . unwords . map (show . v) . transpose . take k . iterate step $ initialize n
```

It seems relatively memory-efficient:

```
% ghc -O2 test && echo 5000 1000 | /usr/bin/time ./test >/dev/null
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, test.o )
Linking test ...
test: <stdin>: hGetLine: end of file
Command exited with non-zero status 1
0.56user 0.01system 0:00.58elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 68924maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+16524minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Comment: Um.. your `v` is acting on individual rows ("layers") at a time which is not the problem statement I am afraid. The ask is to act on individual "columns" each of which span the rows that were produced in the layered fashion.

Comment: @cobra Ah! I did misread. That makes the problem *much* more fun, haha.

Comment: @cobra ...although it doesn't really seem to matter much? After tossing a `transpose` in there it still only appears to take about 70 Mb. I'll edit shortly.

Comment: Thanks, your code tells me how neat `iterate` is, among other things. 
I've edited your code for minor fixes (hope that's fine?). I ran your code with `ghc -no-keep-hi-files -no-keep-o-files -prof -fprof-auto -rtsopts dan.hs && echo "1000 5000 1" | ./dan +RTS -p > /dev/null` and it [took](https://rb.gy/ln4dgq) 2.8 seconds and 2.9 GB which is slightly faster but slightly more space eating than my code, unless I'm misreading it. Anyway, n=k=5000 with limits of 3 sec and 1 GB is what the contest expects which seems out of reach with Haskell :(

Comment: @cobra You appear to be compiling with profiling and without optimizations. Why? Both of those things will make the performance worse. With optimizations and without profiling, I get 1.0s, 500MB resident for `echo 1000 5000 | ./test`.

Comment: Oh my bad, missed `-O2`. With `-O2`, the report says `total alloc = 1,644,437,136 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)`, does it not mean that those many bytes would be used even without profiling?

Comment: @cobra Total allocation is completely different than max residency. If I write a loop that executes a billion times, and in that loop I allocate one byte and then immediately garbage collect it, I will have a max residency of one byte and a total allocation of a billion bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun I put together a version that uses mutable unboxed arrays. I suspect that your original code takes so much memory because it's storing some crazy number of thunks all referencing each other. I didn't bother doing the IO for this one (I really don't think that's the bottleneck), but the following runs in about 200MB max residency (about 1/10 what my more idiomatic answer uses).

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array.ST
import Data.Int

modulus :: Int64
modulus = 10^9+7

initialize :: Int -> Int -> ST s (STUArray s (Int, Int) Int64)
initialize k n = do
    arr <- newArray ((0, 0), (k, n+1)) 0
    forM_ [1..n] $ \m -> writeArray arr (0,m) 1
    forM_ [1..k] $ \j -> do
        forM_ [1..n] $ \m -> do
            up <- readArray arr (j-1, m-1)
            down <- readArray arr (j-1, m+1)
            writeArray arr (j,m) ((up + down) `rem` modulus)
    pure arr

collapse :: STUArray s (Int, Int) Int64 -> ST s (STUArray s Int Int64)
collapse arr = do
    ((xlo,ylo), (xhi,yhi)) <- getBounds arr
    v <- newArray (ylo, yhi) 0
    forM_ [ylo .. yhi] $ \m -> do
        vm <- go m xhi xlo xhi 0
        writeArray v m vm
    pure v
    where
    go m hi j j' acc
        | j > hi = pure acc
        | otherwise = do
            l <- readArray arr (j, m)
            r <- readArray arr (j', m)
            go m hi (j+1) (j'-1) ((acc + (l*r `rem` modulus)) `rem` modulus)

main :: IO ()
main = print (runSTUArray (initialize 5000 5000 >>= collapse))
```